# counter file in php

Tags: php, counter

In this PHP code, we are trying to count users who have downloaded a file.

The problem is, the counter resets after a while. What I want to do is, first of all, force it not to reset and if not possible, set a start number like `8000` rather than `0`.

Here is the code:

```
$myfile = fopen("counter.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$content = fread($myfile, filesize('counter.txt'));
$array = explode(',', $content);

if (isset($_GET["val"])) {
    $val = $_GET["val"];
} else {
    $val = 8000;
}

$indexStr = $array[$val];
$target = intval($indexStr);
$target = $target +1;
$array[$val] = strval($target);
$finalString = implode(",",$array);

$myfile = fopen("counter.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $finalString);

fclose($myfile);
```

The URL this code is a part of is: `avang.ir/ssd-landing`.

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Is there a way to define "after a while"? Does it happen in certain circumstances, or just randomly? I wonder how this code would handle being run by two separate users almost simultaneously, and then wouldn't it be better to use a database table and update it with queries instead?

Comment: It happens randomly

Comment: I could see a situation where two users attempt to download files at virtually the same time, and the first update will be ignored. Why don't you do this in a database table?

Comment: As you see counted number is stored in a text file. I did not develop this code which is used for our Wordpress website. I would appreciate if you tell me how to store counted number in a database table.

Comment: That's a bit outside of the scope of a comment in here, there are plenty of resources on how to update database tables from PHP, and I have no knowledge of Wordpress which might have its own functions. I guess the first question is what you do with the text file - does something else use that, which will be broken if you change it? The query would be as simple as `update dlcount set count = count + 1 where id = <your-id>`, where `<your-id>` is the `$val` value.

Comment: Leaving this behind, is it enough to set val = 8000 to start over counting number of downloads?

Comment: I don't know. Where does 8000 come from? How many downloads do you have? What's the idea of setting it to anything at all - if your code is called without the parameter, should it work, or does it suggest that it's being called maliciously and therefore should do nothing?